# Copy to last non-empty cell in a row

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to copy data from a specific range to last active `cell` in a specific `row`

Right now I use this code:

```
wrkbook1.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
```

It only copies the last active `cell`

Comment: Can you show some picture or explain more? Because not clear. What you want to select...range in a column or range in a row. Tell me more.

Comment: Your range copied is only a cell.  If you want to copy a range first get the range adress that you need to copy.

Comment: @Nicolas, I want to copy E.G., from A1 to Last non-empty `cell` in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too many lines to put into a comment because you have to make sure that the `Cells` inside the `Range` is from the same worksheet.

```
'copy from all of sheet1 columns A
with wrkbook1.Sheets("sheet1")
    .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
end with

'paste to next blank row in sheet2 column A
with wrkbook1.Sheets("sheet2")
    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
end with
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this as well. Now I need to paste some data after last non-empty `cell`. I know there's the Offset option, but I'm not really sure how to use it properly.

Comment: I've added an appropriate `.Paste` cell reference above.

Comment: Damn, I get the Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it myself, I just had to change `Paste` to `PasteSpecial`

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I wrote that off the top of my head and should have tested it. I just don't use `.Paste` enough myself.